# Difference between mvcaction3 and mvcaction4 code snippets in Visual studio?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, code-snippets

Both mvcaction3 and mvcaction4 code snippets generate the same action method code as below. What is the difference between them. I am referring to the short cut mvcaction3 then double tab.

```
public ActionResult Action()
{
    return View();
}
```

Am I missing something?

Press Ctrl+Space, snippets appear. Select mvcaction3 or mvcaction4 - tab+tab  -action method generated. Both the same.

Comment: Its not clear what you are trying to ask.

Comment: Have edited the question.

Comment: Why the votes for closure of the question. Please provide valid reason. I have updated my question on what I am asking. Is it still not clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to Add-New Project-Web. You will see MVC3 and MVC4 projects. Each MVC framework brings its snippets. It just happens that they produce the same result.

Answer (score 3):

These snippets are stored in a file like:

`C:\Program Files\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 4\Visual Studio 2012\Snippets\VC#\1033\ASP.NET MVC 4\mvcaction.snippet` for MVC4 and

`C:\Program Files\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 3\Visual Studio 2012\Snippets\VC#\1033\ASP.NET MVC 3\mvcaction.snippet` for MVC3.

These can be modified(if you want to). But by default they both are the same.